# How to know if my variable is empty (or null) after query - laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to do a permanent delete of previously deleted rows with softdeletes, but when there are no rows to delete my function stops working, I need an "if" for so that this does not happen

my function

```
public function handle()
    {
        $mailMessage = MailMessage::query()->whereNotNull('deleted_at');
        $mailMessage->onDelete();
        $mailTask = MailTask::query()->whereNotNull('deleted_at');
        $mailTask->onDelete();
        $meo = Meo::query()->whereNotNull('deleted_at');
        $meo->onDelete();
        $this->info('Display this on the screen');
    }
```

for example I'm trying to verify that the variable "$mailMessage" is not empty to continue with my function

thanks for read me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use simple [delete](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#deletes):

```
public function handle()
{

  MailMessage::query()->whereNotNull('deleted_at')->delete();
  MailTask::query()->whereNotNull('deleted_at')->delete();
  Meo::query()->whereNotNull('deleted_at')->delete();
      
    $this->info('Display this on the screen');
}
```

added by author: replacing delete for forceDelete is working for me

Comment: thanks, but it didn't delete anything, maybe I should use ondelete?

Comment: are you using SoftDeletes ?

Comment: Yes, on my post I mentioned that, what is the best way to remove them? I have a feeling that forceDelete is not the right way

Answer (score 0):

Use **if($mailMessage){}** then if find any data then you can operation in { this portion. }.